# Pycharm module Adafruit import error

Tags: python-2.7, import, module, pycharm, adafruit

I'm trying to make SPI GUI.
I'm trying to use sample code in Adafruit(ft232h) but i can't run the project

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Kailey/untitled/test1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Adafruit_GPIO.FT232H as FT232H
  File "C:\Users\Kailey\test1\lib\site-packages\Adafruit_GPIO\FT232H.py", line 30, in <module>
    import ftdi1 as ftdi
ImportError: No module named ftdi1
```

How can i solve this problem?